# SQL how to join two tables without duplicate

Tags: sql, join

I have these two tables. I am trying to get the amount in the `item_tbl`, but the `payment_dt` is in another table (`payment_tbl`).

How can I join the two tables and get the amount correctly? Right now, my SQL (using PostgreSQL) generates 3 rows so the amount is multiplied by three when I get the sum.

**item_tbl**:

```
receipt_no | gross_amount | other_discount_amount | net_of_discount_amount 
0000000617 |      2000.00 |                400.00 |                1600.00
```

**payment_tbl**:

```
receipt_no | amount(net) | payment_method | payment_dt
0000000617 |      639.49 | cash           | 2016-05-31 11:48:23.5+08
0000000617 |      500.00 | check          | 2016-05-31 11:48:23.5+08
0000000617 |      500.00 | debit card     | 2016-05-31 11:48:23.5+08
```

**expected result**:

```
gross_amount | other_discount_amount | net_of_discount_amount 
2000.00      |                400.00 |                1600.00
```

Query:

```
SELECT
    cashier.cashier_name,
    COALESCE(gross_amount, 0) AS gross_amount,
    (CASE WHEN item.other_discount_type = 'OTHER' THEN COALESCE(item.other_discount_amount, 0) ELSE 0 END) AS other_discount_amount,
    COALESCE(item.net_of_discount_amount, 0) AS net_of_discount_amount
FROM 
    item_tbl item
INNER JOIN 
    payment_tbl payment ON item.receipt_no = payment.receipt_no
LEFT JOIN 
    cashier_tbl cashier ON cashier.id = item.cashier_id
WHERE 
    date(payment.payment_dt) = to_date('31 May 2016', 'dd Mon YYYY')
```

Comment: Which amount do you need? Please add your expected result

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Unrelated, but: the conversion using `to_date('31 May 2016', 'dd Mon YYYY')`  relies on the current environment. It would e.g. fail on my computer. You should use date values that do not depend on the language, e.g. `31-05-2016`

Comment: Syntax error. (Hint: where clause.)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, was `... WHERE AND date(...` when I commented. (As in the answers.) Is that valid Postgres syntax?

Comment: @jarlh Ah I didn't see the `AND` seems like it has been removed

Comment: edited the where clause. i removed the other filters to simplify the select statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All payment records for a particular receipt must have the same date time for this to work correctly.

```
SELECT
    cashier.cashier_name,
    COALESCE(gross_amount, 0) AS gross_amount,
    (CASE WHEN item.other_discount_type = 'PATRONAGE_CASH' THEN COALESCE(item.other_discount_amount, 0) ELSE 0 END) AS other_discount_amount,
    COALESCE(item.net_of_discount_amount, 0) AS net_of_discount_amount
FROM item_tbl item
    INNER JOIN (Select receipt_no, Max(payment_dt) payment_dt from payment_tbl Group By receipt_no) payment ON item.receipt_no = payment.receipt_no
    LEFT JOIN cashier_tbl cashier ON cashier.id = item.cashier_id
WHERE 
    AND date(payment.payment_dt) = to_date('31 May 2016', 'dd Mon YYYY')
```